# Private field accessible from another instance of the same class

Tags: c#, delegates, field

I do not get the following..I always thought I can access private fields only from class which the field was declared in. However in this case I am able to access it:

```
class Session
{
    List<client> ListOfClients = new List<client>();

    public void IterateClients(Action<client> action)
    {

    }
}

class client
{
    private int A;

    Session area;

    public void SendData()
    {
        area.IterateClients(delegate(client c)
        {
            c.A = 5; //how come this is accessible?
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code that calls `A` is _in_ the `client` class. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically it's not `Session` class that's accessing private `A` variable, it's delegate function created in `SendData()` that does this. There is no problem with that. Think of it as `IterateClients` is just calling method from `client` class, which method can access `A` variable since it is on the same class.

Answer (score 7):

You can only access private data from the CLASS it is a member of. Two objects of the same class can access each other's private parts.

Legal:

```
class c1
{
        private int A;

        public void test(c1 c)
        {
        c.A = 5;

        }

}
```

Illegal:

```
class c2
{
  public void test(c1 c)
  {
     c.A = 5;
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, it might be just me, but I don't think that one object of specific class can access private fields of another object of the same class (as I understand what you've written). This is assuming we're talking about simply accessing private fields without reflection and stuff.

Comment: @Pako: That is not true, as every answer here says.

Comment: No this did not take into account the delegate. But the anonymous delegate is technically a member of client, so it can access the private member.

Comment: Hah, well, I learn something new every day. Never thought that might work. I accept my mistake and will try not to make it again :) Thanks for pointing this out for me.

Answer (score 6):

That's the way it's supposed to work.

Your understanding was incorrect; private members are not limited to the `this` qualifier.

Comment: Exactly, the spec says that private / protected methods accessable from inside the class, not (instanciated) object.

Answer (score 1):

you are right

> I can access private fields only from class which the field was declared in

so u're accessing the private field from the class in which which the private variable is declared. this is allowed in Java too.

Answer (score 1):

You have a method inside class `client`. In this method you give a call to a method of class `Session`. In this call you have a delegate (a kind of "callback"), this delegate runs in the context of class `client` and therefore can access private member `A`.