# Why private field of the class are visible when passing same type as a parameter of method C#?

Tags: c#, private-members

Let see at this class:

```
    public class Cluster
    {
        private List<Point> points; //private field

        public float ComputeDistanceToOtherClusterCLINK(Cluster cluster)
        {
            var max = 0f;
            foreach (var point in cluster.points) // here points field are accessible
            {
                  .......
            }
            return max;
        }
    }
```

why I can access private field?

Can I use this feature or may be it is bad practice?

Comment: This is by design and is particularly useful for static 'factory methods' and 'clone' methods.

Comment: The private fields are accessible inside the type. The ComputeDistanceToOtherClusterCLINK is the member of the same calss. So the private field should be accessible from the method body.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8566307/private-field-accessible-from-another-instance-of-the-same-class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When in doubt, check the language specification.

According to C# language specification, section 3.5.1:

> 3.5.1 Declared accessibility
>
> The declared accessibility of a member can be one of the following:
>
> - Public, which is selected by including a public modifier in the member declaration. The intuitive meaning of public is “access not limited”.
> - Protected, which is selected by including a protected modifier in the member declaration. The intuitive meaning of protected is “access limited to the containing class or types derived from the containing class”.
>   -Internal, which is selected by including an internal modifier in the member declaration. The intuitive meaning of internal is “access limited to this program”.
> - Protected internal (meaning protected or internal), which is selected by including both a protected and an internal modifier in the member declaration. The intuitive meaning of protected internal is “access limited to this program or types derived from the containing class”.
> - Private, which is selected by including a private modifier in the member declaration. The intuitive meaning of private is “access limited to the containing type”.

As you can see from the last section, all methods of the *containing class* (in your case, it's `Cluster`) have access to the private field `points`.

...and no, this is not a bad practice at all: this is precisely the purpose of private fields!

Answer (score 8):

> why I can access private field?

Because you are inside the same class in which the private field is defined.

Answer (score 3):

Private means private to the class scope. What is surprising is, that you can even access the private fields of another object of the same class.

```
public class A
{
    private int _i;

    public bool AreEqual(A otherObject)
    {
        return this._i == otherObject._i;
    }
}
```

---

One of the main aspects of OOP (Object Oriented Programming) is encapsulation. This means that an object forbids the direct access to is private data (fields). Instead it provides public methods (including property getters and setters) to manipulate and access its data. But this also means that these methods must be able to access these private fields, otherwise private fields would be completely pointless.

---

Clarification: But I agree, that being able to access another object's private members, is unexpected and, at least partially, violates the encapsulation principle.

Comment: "Completely pointless"? Suppose I introduced a keyword called `superprivate` along with the specification that a superprivate class member is accessible only through the `this` reference. So if I said `superprivate List<Point> points;` then this field `points` would be accessible inside a method in the same class, saying e.g. `points.Add(p);` or equivalently `this.points.Add(p)`. But according to the spec of `superprivate`, saying `otherCluster.points.Add(p)` would be illegal. I think that keyword `superprivate` could be meaningful. It's just more restrictive than `private`, not pointless.

Comment: What I mean is, that a `private` field (with the actual definition of `private`) would be pointless, if it could not be access from within a method of the same class, because then nobody could access this field ever. Inside the scope of a class, every instance member is automatically `this.member`.

Comment: That's correct. But look at the original question. There, `cluster.points` is different from `this.points` because `cluster` is (generally) another object than `this`, and their `points` lists will (in general) be different. The Original Poster was surprised that it was OK to say `cluster.points` when `cluster` was a different object (from `this`). So a "private" instance field can be seen by another object's instance method.

Comment: Hmm, upon reading your answer again, I'm sure we both agree on all this :-)

Answer (score 2):

You define the field within the scope of the class, and therefore things within that class can access the private field. This is well-defined behavior and can be very useful, not bad programming practice at all.

A look at [Scope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691132%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) may be useful to you.

Answer (score 2):

The private keyword makes the field private to the class, not to an object instance of that class.  So, any code inside that class can access that field in any object that is of that class' type (provided it has a reference to the object, of course).  It is not at all bad practice to do so.

Answer (score 2):

> Private fields are always accessible in the scope in which it is
>   defined and since private variable is defined in class scope hence it
>   is accessible.

Answer (score 2):

The private fields are accessible inside the type. The ComputeDistanceToOtherClusterCLINK is the member of the same calss. So the private field should be accessible from the method body.